# Notation for Number of elements in vector

Tags: notation

I have a matlab vector like `s=[1 2 3 4]'` and iterate over every element:

```
for i=1:length(s)
  cal_function(s(i));
end
```

what is the correct mathematic notation of the `length`-Function?
I found some papers which write the length as $|s|$ but I don't know if this is correct as I have never seen this before.

Comment: $|s|$ usually refers to the Euclidean length of the vector, i.e., $\sqrt{s_1+s_2+\dots+s_d}$, where $d$ is the dimensionality of the vector (4 in your case). So I don't think $|s|$ or $||s||$ is the notation you want to use, since you seem to be referring to the number of elements in $s$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That depends on the context. When thinking of vectors, especially in finite-dimensional normed spaces, $\lvert \cdot\rvert$ sometimes is used to denote the norm (though most of the time, $\lVert\cdot\rVert$ is used for that). At those times, the length is usually clear from the context or entirely immaterial.

When talking about abstract tuples, it's almost always the length (number of entries) of the tuple, and I'm not aware of any other common notation.

Comment: I've upvoted this answer. I've there are no other Answers in the next few days I'll accept it.

Comment: @jrast: Sure, no hurry. :)

Comment: I think what OP meant was to have a notation of the number of elements in $s$ and not the Euclidean length of $s$.